# jQuery Show/Hide Multiple Table Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little table where I would like to hide some of the details with a simple button... let us say,

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Show/Hide Details</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Nickname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Revan D. Cole</td>
      <td>Revan</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>revan.dcole@domain.com</td>
      <td>(+1) 123 123</td>
      <td>D Cole Street</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mira Rosenfield</td>
      <td>Mira</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>mira.rosenfield@domain.com</td>
      <td>(+2) 234 234</td>
      <td>Rose Street</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I wanted to hide this Email, Phone, and Address fields when the button is clicked, and it will shows the details again if we click it.

Comment: I don't see any Javascript or jQuery here. Have you tried anything, or are you asking SO to write your whole script for you? (that's not what SO is here for)

Comment: Hopefully it's just being new, but echoing what CertainPerformance said. See this for info on asking good questions at SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is to assign a class to all the info which you want to toggle. This really makes the solution simple.

I have assigned a class `sensitive` in this example, and toggled it when the button is clicked.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".sensitive").toggle();
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.sensitive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show/Hide Details</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Nickname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th class="sensitive">Email</th>
    <th class="sensitive">Phone</th>
    <th class="sensitive">Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Revan D. Cole</td>
      <td>Revan</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td class="sensitive">revan.dcole@domain.com</td>
      <td class="sensitive">(+1) 123 123</td>
      <td class="sensitive">D Cole Street</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mira Rosenfield</td>
      <td>Mira</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td class="sensitive">mira.rosenfield@domain.com</td>
      <td class="sensitive">(+2) 234 234</td>
      <td class="sensitive">Rose Street</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I never though that it would be this easy! I did appreciate your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

You want to hide last three child of `td and th` , you can select last three child by `nth-last-child(-n+3)` [for more info](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

How does nth-last-child work

```
(-n+3)....
 -1+3 = 2  --> nth-last-child(2)
 -2+3 = 1  --> nth-last-child(1)
 -3+3 = 0  --> nth-last-child(0)
```

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  $("tr td:nth-last-child(-n+3),th:nth-last-child(-n+3)").toggle();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show/Hide Details</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Nickname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Revan D. Cole</td>
      <td>Revan</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>revan.dcole@domain.com</td>
      <td>(+1) 123 123</td>
      <td>D Cole Street</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mira Rosenfield</td>
      <td>Mira</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>mira.rosenfield@domain.com</td>
      <td>(+2) 234 234</td>
      <td>Rose Street</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I love the way you provide the answer! But I think I will go for the easy one bellow.
Anyway, I did really appreciate your help!